I want to use Transaction atomic with flask
I've experience of using transaction atomic decorator in django but now i'm using flask framework. Can anyone suggest me what is the equivalent for the same. I'm dealing with mongodb and mysql at the same time.
I'm trying to achieve transaction atomic in flask.

Assuming using Flask-MySQLdb/ which uses  mysqlclient where an explicit commit is needed on connection object. auto_commit is disabled.

i want to achieve atomic transaction for pymongo
